# Callback in STM32 isn't called

Tags: c, callback, stm32

Trying to make simple PWM transmitter i faced with a problem. I have TIM2 with Channel2 (in PWM Generation mode) on board NUCLEO F042K6 and USART1 connected to the board in Async mode (USART works in DMA).

I wanted to make a PWM transmitter that uses a circular buffer that can be filled with one character or several characters at once. The plan was that when the user enters a character (or several characters), the idle line callback is processed, in which a function is called that stores the data in a cyclic buffer. After saving, the data transferred to the buffer is passed to the function *PWM_SendChar(...)* to convert the data into bits and transfer them over the PWM line. **But** the problem is when the program goes into *PWM_SendChar(...)* the callback *HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(...)* isn't called and program stucks in infinite while loop because variable used as a flag for detecting the end of single pulse (*PWM_data_sent_flag*) wasn't set to value 1.

However, if I use *HAL_UART_Recieve(...)* func in *while(1)* loop (located in *main(void)*) to recieve a char from user program works fine without stucking in while loop in TIM callback. Ofc, for this method I don't use *HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(...)* and cycle buffer.

Thats's why I think the problem is in USART idle line detection and please help me solve it.

**Code Example**

---

Global variable used for waiting the end of pulse:

```
volatile uint16_t PWM_data_sent_flag = 0;
```

PWM timer callback:

```
void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim->Instance == TIM2) {
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
        PWM_data_sent_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Callback for USART idle line:

```
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size) {
    if (huart == &huart1) {
//      Function_to_save_input_char_in_cycle_buffer() is called
    }
}
```

Function used to send char as a PWM signal (emited after *Function_to_save_input_char_in_cycle_buffer()* completed):

```
void PWM_SendChar(char ch) {
    for (int i = 0, mv = 7; i <= 7; ++i, --mv) {
        uint8_t bit = (ch & (1 << mv)) ? 1 : 0;

        // PWM_LOW_PERCENT encodes bit with zero value, PWM_HIGH_PERCENT encodes bit with value one
        uint16_t duty_cycle = bit == 0 ? PWM_LOW_PERCENT : PWM_HIGH_PERCENT; 

        // Change TIM2 CCR2 value according to bit's value
        __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2,
                GET_PERCENT_VALUE(TIM2->ARR, duty_cycle));

        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
       
        // Program comes to this cycle and doesn't leave it
        while (!PWM_data_sent_flag)
            ;
        PWM_data_sent_flag = 0;
    }
}
```

USART receive to idle launch (half data transmitted callback disabled):

```
int main(void) {
//  Init code  
//  ...

    if (HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, (uint8_t*) ring_buf.buff,
            ARRAY_LEN(ring_buf.buff)) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    // Disable half word transmitted callback
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT); 

    while(1) {
    }
}
```

TIM2 settings:

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = { 0 };
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = { 0 };
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = { 0 };

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
    htim2.Instance = TIM2;
    htim2.Init.Prescaler = 48000 - 1;
    htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim2.Init.Period = 100 - 1;
    htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig)
            != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2)
            != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
    HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}
```

USART1 settings:

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}
```

DMA settings:

```
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) {

    /* DMA controller clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* DMA interrupt init */
    /* DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: Your description of the program is pretty long, but it's very confusingly worded (and your code style makes it hard to read, although not incorrect, with all those ? for if). When you're in that hanging loop, it means your timer is still supposed to be running. Check the registers for Timer2 in debugging. Does the counter actually start and go? And what are the timer's flags in the hanging loop?

Comment: So reading UART and PWM done is both done using interrupts?
I think the reason for why it works when you are reading UART from main loop is that you are not in interrupt context.